# How to disable loading particular code blocks on small screens/touch screens in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, touchscreen

I'm planning to build a responsive site with Bootstrap 3. I have modules (code blocks) that I don't need to be loaded on small screens or on touch sceeens. As far as I know, due to loading times it's a good practice to prevent loading of these unnecessary modules, not just hide them after loading. But as far as I know Bootstrap itself doesn't have control on loading code blocks, it's just about displaying already loaded things.

My question is that what technique should I use for this purpose? It's clear that it's two separate ways of using: not to load on small screens or not to load on touch screens. I'm interested in both! Is this a good idea to use such things along with Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.visible-desktop` class to make certain elements only visible to non-mobile devices.

See here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: That's just about show/hide already loaded code. I'm looking for a solution for not to load parts of the code depending on screen size and/or type.

Comment: Couldn't you put the script in one of the responsive divs?

Comment: I could but as I wrote: "As far as I know, due to loading times it's a good practice to prevent loading of these unnecessary modules, not just hide them after loading."